# Two separated tables vs One table with two columns

Tags: sql-server, database, winforms, database-design, database-schema

I am creating a windows forms application that must control the entry and exit of people in an office building. These people may be visitors or employees, and everybody must use an access card at the building entrance. A card will be programmed temporarily when the person is a visitor, and the employees should use their own cards. My doubt is about my database. Is there a way to do this nicely? The cards (no matter if it is an employee or visitor ) has a strong key to the ratchet can identify it wich comes from the manufacturer of turnstiles and I can't change it. So, my structure is:

In my database, I have a table where I keep the cards. When someone try to get inside the building, the turnstile sends to my system the date and time of access and the card code. Now I do not know how to separate the employees and visitors. Should I have a separated flow table to employees and visitors? For the employees flow table, I get the employees card from the card table using the same ID. In the visitor flow table, I need to know who is the visitor using the temporary card (the key to the temporary card never changes, so I can not rely on me only in the key). Or should I only have a flow table with a Visitor_ID and Worker_ID column , one of which will always be null (so I know if it was an employee or a visitor by the field with a value).

Can anyone tell me which of the two is more applicable and why?

Comment: Can't you have a column called IsEmployee which stores a 0 or 1 to indicate whether she's an employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Employees and visitors are both people.  Specifically people that may (or may not) have an access card assigned to them.

I would have one People table that has a foreign key relationship to the AccessCard table.  If you only care about whether the person is an employee or visitor, but the information you store is otherwise identical, a boolean column is fine.  If your system stores additional information for employees and/or visitors, create an Employees and Visitors table, and have a foreign key relationship from People to each of those.

Comment: Thanks @Eric-J. I can give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

I would create single table to store both employee and visitor then add an extra column for Type(E, V).